# Primefaces p:calendar, value incorrectly set

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I've been looking into date formatting and time zone setting, but still can't get the correct value I selected in my managedBean. I tried different days, months and years to no good results, since it seems to be setting hours instead of the month, keeping January as the month selected no matter which one I'm choosing. As i didn't see a similar problem, i decided to post my issue here. Any help appreciated.

Here's the code in my JSF page :

```
<p:calendar pattern="dd-mm-yyyy" locale="fr" value="#{modBean.dateEmp}">
    <h:outputScript name="js/fr.js"/>
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="@this"/>
</p:calendar>
```

And here's the code in my managedBean :

```
public void setDateEmp(Date dateEmp) 
{
    System.out.println("dateEmp param : "+dateEmp);
    DateFormat df=DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.FRANCE);  
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
    String dateFormate=df.format(dateEmp);
    System.out.println("dateformate : "+dateFormate);
    try 
    {
        this.dateEmp=df.parse(dateFormate);
        System.out.println(this.dateEmp);
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And finally, this is what I am getting in the console for the three prints (for the example I chose "1st August 2014") :

```
dateEmp param : Wed Jan 01 00:08:00 CET 2014
dateformate : 01/01/14
Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2014
```

Could someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in the `pattern`.

```
<p:calendar ... pattern="dd-mm-yyyy" />
```

The `pattern` is based on `SimpleDateFormat` rules. If you carefully read its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you'll discover that `mm` stands for **minutes**, not months.

For months, you need `MM`.

```
<p:calendar ... pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
```